# Nuxt Serverless AWS Lambda: How to use loadNuxt with serverless-http?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, async-await, nuxt.js, serverless

I am trying to SSR render Nuxt with the help of an AWS lambda function. I want to use the programatic [`nuxt.render`](https://nuxtjs.org/api/nuxt-render) method and prepare an express middle ware as follows:

```
// nuxt.js
const { loadNuxt } = require('nuxt')
const app = require('express')()

const nuxt = async () => {
  const nuxt = await loadNuxt('start')
  app.use(nuxt.render)
  return app
}

module.exports = nuxt
})
```

Unfortunately the needed `loadNuxt` function is async. I am trying to use [serverless-http](https://github.com/dougmoscrop/serverless-http) for mounting the express app

```
// index.js
const sls = require('serverless-http')
const binaryMimeTypes = require('./binaryMimeTypes.js')
const nuxt = require('./nuxt')

module.exports.nuxt = sls(nuxt, {
  binary: binaryMimeTypes
})
```

Trying the above results in a loading page, which never finishes loading. This is due to loadNuxt being async. How do I prepare the async express app for the http-serverless plugin?

---

If I await `loadNuxt` I get a 404 page

```
// index.js
const sls = require('serverless-http')
const binaryMimeTypes = require('./binaryMimeTypes.js')
const nuxt = require('./nuxt')

module.exports.nuxt = async (event, context) => {
  const app = await nuxt()
  const handler = sls(app, {
    binary: binaryMimeTypes
  })
  const result = await handler(event, context)
  return result
}
```

---

Executing the following with `node nuxt.js` works just fine

```
// nuxt.js
const { loadNuxt } = require('nuxt')
const app = require('express')()

const nuxt = async () => {
  const nuxt = await loadNuxt('start')
  app.use(nuxt.render)
  app.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0')
}
nuxt()
```